# Newline in a WPF-label?

Tags: wpf, label, newline

How can I add a newline in the text of a label in WPF such as the following?

```
<Label>Lorem 
  ipsum</Label>
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

```
<Label><TextBlock>Lorem<LineBreak/>ipsum</TextBlock></Label>
```

You need to use TextBlock because TextBlock accepts as children a collection of Inline objects. So you are giving the TextBlock element three Inline items: Run Text="Lorem", LineBreak, and Run Text="ipsum".

You can't do the following:

```
<Label>Lorem<LineBreak/>ipsum</Label>`
```

because a label accepts one content child element.

Also, not sure exactly what your use case is but notice I placed a TextBlock inside your Label element. Is it repetitive? Not really, depending on your need. Here's a good article on the differences between the two elements: [Difference between Label and TextBlock](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/)

Comment: When I tried the answer above, I got an error for having a tag in the middle of my content. Instead, I used this:

`<TextBlock>
 <Run>First</Run>
 <LineBreak/>
 <Run>Second</Run> 
</TextBlock>`

Comment: This works great but is not useful when using localization. In that case use `Lorem&#x0a;Ipsum`

Answer (score 134):

in WPF you can use the value `"&#10;"` or `"&#xA;"`

For example:

```
<Label Content="Lorem&#10;ipsum" />
```

("10" is the ASCII number for newline)

or

```
<Label Content="Lorem&#xA;ipsum" />
```

("A" is the ASCII number for newline in hex)

[image: Example, with a border arround label to show boundry]

Comment: Agreed this should be the accepted answer. It's more elegant and simpler to use.

Comment: This works fine if put straight into the XAML, but does not seem to work when put into a resource string - it just displays Lorem&#x0a;Ipsum in the label. As @stijn pointed out, this is what is required for localisation, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

When doing this in the ViewModel or Model, I have found that using Environment.NewLine has the most consistent outcome, including localization. It should work directly in the View as well, but I haven't tested that.

Example:

In the View

```
<Label Content="{Binding SomeStringObject.ParameterName}" />
```

In the ViewModel:

```
SomeStringObject.ParameterName = "First line" + Environment.NewLine + "Second line";
```

Answer (score 4):

An example of how to add a ToolTip with multiple lines to a control, such as a button. The tooltip is width limited so it will wrap if a sentence is too wide.

```
<!-- Button would need some properties to make it clickable.-->
<Button>
   <Button.ToolTip>
      <TextBlock Text="Line 1&#x0a;Line 2" MaxWidth="300" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Tested on VS2019 + .NET 4.6.1 + WPF.

Answer (score 3):

```
<Label xml:space="preserve">text content
another line</Label>
```

seems to work too

Comment: This does what the question asks, but one caveat is that it also preserves whitespace. So "nicely formatted" text in XAML will include all those indenting spaces, too.