# What the best way to get paragraphs in a WPF textblock? (newline chars?)

Tags: wpf, newline, textblock

I have some text which has "\r\n" newline markers. I would like to have the newlines in a WPF textblock. I've tried replacing "\r\n" with "& # 13;" (without the spaces), which worked when I set the Text property in XAML, but doesn't seem to work when setting from the C# code-behind.

So...what's the standard way to convert "\r\n" to newlines in a WPF textblock?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try these for a more WPF centric solution.

```
TextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("First"));
TextBlock.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
TextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Second"));
```

See also : [XAML based Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483802/newline-in-a-wpf-label)

Answer (score 6):

```
textBlock.Text = string.Format("One{0}Two", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Maybe doesn't work with SL? Anyway, I misread your question - see my updated answer. It works with WPF - not sure about SL.

Comment: Thx for your replies. I've chosen Ash's answer, being WPF centric and as such it seems like the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

When writing C# I always use "System.Environment.Newline" for the newline carriage return.

It means that you don't have to worry about character coding or what destination OS uses.

I have also found it to work on WPF GUI when called from the underlying .cs file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In this case I've gone with the WPF-centric solution.