# WPF Multiline TextBlock LineBreak issues

Tags: wpf, textblock

I have the following code

```
txtBlock1.Inlines.Add("This is first paragraph \n This is second paragraph");
```

then TextBlock would display:

```
This is first paragraph
This is second paragraph
```

But, if I have the following (which I though is equivalent);

```
txtBlock1.Inlines.Add("This is first paragraph");
txtBlock1.Inlines.Add("\n");
txtBlock1.Inlines.Add("This is second paragraph");
```

TextBlock display:

```
This is first paragraph // but second paragraph missing
```

If I separate out the linebreak then the rest of text after the linebreak doesn't show. Why?

I have to use run:

```
Run run1 = new Run();
run1.Text = "First Paragraph";
run1.Text += "\n";
run1.Text += "Second Paragraph";
txtBlock1.Inlines.Add(run1);
```

Then it produce the result correctly. Why I cannot add inline text to `Textblock` and require me to use `Run`?

Comment: omg...it's actually a bug in VS2010 Ultimate. Sometext won't show until I resize the window... if someone happen to come across this, resize the window

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this answer: [What the best way to get paragraphs in a WPF textblock? (newline chars?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559754/what-the-best-way-to-get-paragraphs-in-a-wpf-textblock-newline-chars)

You need:

```
txtBlock1.Inlines.Add("This is first paragraph");
txtBlock1.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
txtBlock1.Inlines.Add("This is second paragraph");
```